# Pass variable to MYSQL from android app

Tags: java, android, mysql

Im trying to pass the output of the latitude and longitude to a MySQL database through this android app, but I don't know where to start.

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did my answer help up? :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that establishing a direct connection to mysql would be a good idea (at all). So I would suggest doing the following:

Build a simple **restful php application** that will receive your data as a **POST request from your android app** and than stores it into the MySQL database.

- [a framework to rapidly build a rest app in PHP](http://www.slimframework.com/)
- [intruduction and tutorial to google volley - how to make a POST request](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put)

I think this combination will do a good and clean job.

**Alternative**: If you think this the restful part overkill, you can just leave this part out and do it with a simple php script.